# Why my checkbox items's state is not persisting inside Bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I have a `checkbox` inside a [Bootstrap Modal](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp). When I checked it close the model it did not remain checked if I re-open the modal dialog.

I have the list named as `$scope.price` from which the item will come based on some condition. If I select the "The Washing" from drop down list then the modal will be open having the Items of Washing. Following is my code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Washing" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button"  class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <table border="1">
            <tr ng-repeat="y in price">
            <td> {{ y.name }} </td>

            <td> {{ y.cost }} </td>
            <td> <input type="checkbox" value={{y.name}} ng-model="servicess[1].checked"> </td>
            </tr>
            </table>         
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit"  class="b1">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$scope.call = function(value)
{
    if(value=="washing")
    {
        $scope.price = [{
            "name": "Washing1",
            "cost": 500
            }, {
            "name": "Washing2",
            "cost": 600
            }, {
            "name": "Washing3",
            "cost": 700
        }];
    }
    else if(value=="wheel_align")
    {
        $scope.price = [{
            "name": "Wheel_Align1",
            "cost": 150
            }, {
            "name": "Wheel_Align2",
            "cost": 160
            }, {
            "name": "Wheel_Align3",
            "cost": 170
        }];
    }
    else if(value=="full_service")
    {
        $scope.price = [{
            "name": "full_service1",
            "cost": 15
            }, {
            "name": "Full Service2",
            "cost": 66
            }, {
            "name": "full_service3",
            "cost": 67
            }];
        }
};

$(".b1").on('click', function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
        if($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
            servicess.push($(this).val());
        }
        alert(servicess);
    }); 

    for(var i=0;i<servicess.length;i++)
    {
        $('input[type=checkbox][value='+servicess[i]+']').prop('checked',true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you setup the `for loop` on purpose or for just the workaround?

Comment: Just for Work Around

Comment: Try removing the loop and see what you get.

Comment: Nothing Found ... and if I remove the loop then how can i iterate over the array

Comment: That is why i asked you the purpose of putting loop. Besides that, I see only one `checkbox` in HTML, why do you need loop over an `array`? I think you can set up the checked property directly. You need to revise the code, can you create a fiddle for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one may be it help you

```
$(".b1").on('click', function() { $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){ if($(this).prop("checked") == true) { servicess.push($(this).val()); } alert(servicess); });
```

$('input[type=checkbox][value='+servicess[i]+']').prop('checked',true); });